# Xamarin.Android Record Video - Quality Poor

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using the following Xamarin tutorial https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/media/video/record_video/

I can successfully record video and audio however the quality is not very good. Can anyone suggest/explain how I can increase the quality please?

I know the device can record in higher quality because the native camera app record in much higher quality.

EDIT here is my code so far

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.RecordVideo);
            var record = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Record);
            var stop = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Stop);
            var play = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Play);
            var video = FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.SampleVideoView);
            var videoPlayback = FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.PlaybackVideoView);
            string path = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "/test.mp4";


            if (Camera.NumberOfCameras < 2)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Front camera missing", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                return;
            }
            video.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            videoPlayback.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;

            _camera = Camera.Open(1);
            _camera.SetDisplayOrientation(90);
            _camera.Unlock();

            recorder = new MediaRecorder();

            recorder.SetCamera(_camera);

            recorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.Mic);
            recorder.SetVideoSource(VideoSource.Camera);

            recorder.SetOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Default);
            recorder.SetAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.Default);
            recorder.SetVideoEncoder(VideoEncoder.Default);
            //var cameraProfile = CamcorderProfile.Get(CamcorderQuality.HighSpeed1080p);
           // recorder.SetProfile(cameraProfile);
            recorder.SetOutputFile(path);

            recorder.SetOrientationHint(270);

            recorder.SetPreviewDisplay(video.Holder.Surface);

            record.Click += delegate
            {

                recorder.Prepare();
                recorder.Start();
            };


            stop.Click += delegate
            {
                if (recorder != null)
                {      
                    video.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                    videoPlayback.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                    recorder.Stop();
                    recorder.Release();                    
                }
            };

            play.Click += delegate
            {
                video.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                videoPlayback.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(path);
                videoPlayback.SetVideoURI(uri);
                videoPlayback.Start();
            };

        }
```

Comment: Hello,
How you solve this issue I can't add CamcorderProfile

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the example specifying the [CamcorderProfile](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Media.CamcorderProfile/) anywhere so you might want to start from that. It's possible that the default framerate, bitrate and video frame size are lower than you'd expect. I'm not an a computer right now but try to set the profile to for example [QUALITY_1080p](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html#QUALITY_1080P) using the SetProfile method in MediaRecorder.

You need to set the profile after setting the video and audio sources but before calling SetOutputFile method.

Comment: I have added the code I'm using, I have tried adding the CamcorderProfile  (commented out in the snippet above) but with this in the app just crashes out. Am I adding this in the correct place?

Comment: Hmm, not sure what's up with that. I can't get to the computer yet but could you try to add `recorder.SetVideoEncodingBitRate(3000000);` instead of the recorder.SetProfile? I think that your main problem is a very low bitrate so this should fix it. You can also set the frame size to Full HD by hand: `recorder.SetVideoSize(1920, 1080)`